# Match 2 csv files and write the third cell of the second file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wrote this code to compare two `CSV files (f1 and f2)` which both have 3 columns and many rows, then each time an `item at cell 1 of f1 matches that of f2` and `item at cell 2 of f1 matches that of f2, it should write the values`cell1 of f1, cell2 of f1, cell 3 of f2, for each respective column to a file named `network_python.csv`

**The code:**

```
t = {}
with open('file1.csv') as ff:
    for f1 in csv.DictReader(ff):
        with open('file2.csv') as ff:
            for f2 in csv.DictReader(ff):
                if int(f1['From'].strip()) == int(f2['From'].strip()) and int(f1['To'].strip()) == int(f2['To'].strip()):
                    print (f1['From'], f1['To'], f2['Mode'])
                    t.update({'From': f1['From'], 'To': f1['To'], 'Mode': f2['Mode']})

with open('network_python.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['From', 'To', 'Mode']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for k,v in t.iteritems():
        writer.writerow(t)
```

**Sample data in file1.csv**

```
From    To  Mode
1   2   cw
2   1   cw
3   4   cwt
7   2   cbt
8   9   ct
```

**Sample data in file2.csv**

```
From    To  Mode
8   9   c
3   4   cw
1   2   cwt
7   2   ct
2   1   cb
```

The code works fine (ie gets the right output) but when writing to file it writes to one single row thereby overwriting the previous result. Also is there a way I can improve the code's efficiency? as it is quite slow with large files. I have searched some questions here but they don't exactly answer my question Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `dict` where key is `(from, to)` from both csv files and combine them for the result:

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict

with open('file1.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    reader.next()
    rows = OrderedDict((tuple(row[:2]), None) for row in reader)

with open('file2.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    reader.next()

    # Skip row if matching row wasn't present in file1.csv
    rows.update({tuple(row[:2]): row[2] for row in reader if tuple(row[:2]) in rows})

with open('network_python.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['From', 'To', 'Mode']
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(fieldnames)

    # Skip row if it wasn't present in file2.csv
    writer.writerows((k[0], k[1], v) for k, v in rows.iteritems() if v is not None)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure but lists should be slightly more efficient in your case (iteration, memory and no look up). However, dictionnaries are extremely efficient to look up values. Also, you don't need to convert to integer and use strip when comparing. This code should work fine.

```
import csv

output = []
with open('file1.csv') as file1, open('file2.csv') as file2:
    for f1 in csv.DictReader(file1, delimiter='\t'):
        for f2 in csv.DictReader(file2, delimiter='\t'):
            if f1['From'] == f2['From'] and f1['To'] == f2['To']:
                new_item = [f1['From'], f1['To'], f2['Mode']]
                print new_item
                output.append(new_item)

with open('network_python.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['From', 'To', 'Mode']
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(fieldnames)
    for row in output:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Glad I can help, can you tag the post as the correct answer please ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking load all files to memory than compare them.

```
    import csv

    with open(file1Path,'rb') as f:
        r = csv.reader(f)
        res1 = [line for line in f]

    with open(file2Path,'rb') as f:
        r = csv.reader(f)
    res2 = [line for line in f]

    final = [ [file1col[0],file1col[1],file2col[2]]for file1col,file2col in zip(res1,res2) if file1col[0] == file2cole[0] and file1col[1] == file2col[1] ]

    with open(finalPath,'wb') as f:
      w = csv.writer(f)
      w.writerow(['From','To','Mode'])
      w.writerows(final)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to not modify the "t" `dict` each time you get a new row and use generators  instead of it

```
def get_row():
    with open('file1.csv') as ff:
        for f1 in csv.DictReader(ff):
            with open('file2.csv') as ff:
                for f2 in csv.DictReader(ff):
                    if int(f1['From'].strip()) == int(f2['From'].strip()) and int(f1['To'].strip()) == int(f2['To'].strip()):
                        print (f1['From'], f1['To'], f2['Mode'])
                        yield {'From': f1['From'], 'To': f1['To'], 'Mode': f2['Mode']}

with open('network_python.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['From', 'To', 'Mode']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for k,v in t.iteritems():
        writer.writerow(get_row())
```